# Behat fails to init: Declaration of Client::createResponse() should be compatible with createResponse()

Tags: php, behat, mink

I am trying to set-up Behat but it fails to init when I run `bin/behat --init`. My `composer.json` is taken from the official [docs](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html):

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable",
        "behat/mink": "1.4.*@stable",
        "behat/mink-extension": "*",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
}
```

The `composer install` works fine and looks like all dependencies get installed.

```
# behat.yml
default:
  paths:
    features:  features
    bootstrap: features/bootstrap

  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~

annotations:
  paths:
    features: features/annotations

closures:
  paths:
    features: features/closures
```

Running `# bin/behat --init` yields the following error:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of Behat\Mink\Driver\Goutte\Client::createResponse() should be compatible with Goutte\Client::createResponse(GuzzleHttp\Message\Response $response) in /web/Test-1/vendor/behat/mink-goutte-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/Goutte/Client.php on line 23

Strict Standards: Declaration of Behat\Mink\Driver\Goutte\Client::createResponse() should be compatible with Goutte\Client::createResponse(GuzzleHttp\Message\Response $response) in /web/Test-1/vendor/behat/mink-goutte-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/Goutte/Client.php on line 23


  [ReflectionException]
  Class Guzzle\Http\Client does not exist
```

Could somebody tell me why?
I did everything exactly like in official article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incompatible versions of Mink extensions / drivers. The following pulls the latest versions compatible (right now) with Behat 3 and Mink 1.6, while you want to use much older versions (2.4.* and 1.4.* respectively).

```
"behat/mink-extension": "*",
"behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
"behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*"
```

I am assuming you've pulled this from the Internet, as I can't find a different example out there with fixed versions, which is pretty ironic, as the same people are probably blogging at the same time about how much of a bad practice that is. If you are just beginning, I suggest you stick with the latest versions of Behat and Mink, they are much better and have been more than stable for the past 6 months. Change you composer.json and update the dependencies:

```
"behat/behat": "*",
"behat/mink": "*"
```

If not, go to each extension / driver repo and find the tagged version from early-mid 2013, that should fix it for the older packages.

**Update**

The code you provided doesn't work because you are using the old config format with the new Behat / Mink version. Don't forget, Behat 2 configs must be upgraded for Behat 3. [Documentation](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/#guides) is still pretty poor, but the basics are covered rather well [here](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/6.profiles.html) and [here](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/5.suites.html). Updating your config to this resolves the issue:

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~

  suites:
    default:
      paths: 
        - '%paths.base%/features'

    annotations:
      paths:
        - '%paths.base%/features/annotations'

    closures:
      paths:
        - '%paths.base%/features/closures'
```

Here are the the packed [files](http://cl.ly/1T1z072E3N2Q), just in case you get lost, the init command produces this:

```
Ian-Bytcheks-MacBook-Pro:behat ianbytchek$ php ./vendor/bin/behat --init
+d features - place your *.feature files here
+d features/bootstrap - place your context classes here
+f features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php - place your definitions, transformations and hooks here
+d features/annotations - place your *.feature files here
+d features/closures - place your *.feature files here
```

[image]

**Update**

The root of all evil was the curl module, that was not installed in the author's environment. Instead of a proper warning php tried to mitigate the problem by using an alternative, which didn't help much.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work out. I put * for all lines and I got versions: `behat/behat (v2.5.3)`, `behat/mink (v1.4.3)`, `behat/mink-extension (v1.3.1)`, `behat/mink-browserkit-driver (v1.0.5)`, `behat/mink-goutte-driver (v1.0.3)` but i got the same error.

Comment: Funny enough, that is not a problem indeed. But one day it will be if you don't use proper versions! :) I've tested it with the example in the documentation, and [it works fine](http://cl.ly/image/0A0U303Y0G07), meaning the problem is related to your code. Provide your feature code, behat.yml, and any custom context that you use.

Comment: There is a zip file with everything, files and logs
http://pushkarov.com/files/misc/Other/behat.zip
I do not include .feature file because i haven't gone this far yet, it fails on stage of --init.

Comment: That's interesting, you talking about Behat v3 and I see in your composer.lock (do i need it?) I see that you have v3.0.14 but when i run this composer.json i am getting v2.5.3

Comment: When i change composer.json to `"behat/behat": "3.*"` i am getting error, log is here: http://pushkarov.com/files/misc/Other/v3error.txt

Comment: Hm, that shouldn't be happening. I just deleted the lock, ran `composer install` inside the folder I've sent and this is the [result](https://gist.github.com/ianbytchek/f8f70abfbe8a4e76fa41) I get. Just in case, this is the [composer.json](https://gist.github.com/ianbytchek/bf96283dbc9e6ee02bc3). The lock ensures that when you make an install you get the exact same packages as per the lock file, just make sure you do `composer install` not `composer update`.

Comment: You are not using the composer I've sent – you have earlier extension / driver versions, not `*`, and they are conflicting with `*` Behat / Mink. Just unpack the [zip](http://cl.ly/1T1z072E3N2Q), do `composer install`, and then everything should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you told me! (Proof https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcWRFM5n-kY) but it loads me 2.5 and looks like it is right behaviour because Behar web by default refers to doc of 2.5 as stable. I do not know why it loads 3 for you... anyway, I managed to install v3 through composer tool in PhpStorm IDE, used your .yml file and looks like it works! So thank you! I am going to mark your answer as solution but we need to do something with it because it is still confusing (* does not load v3 for me and most likely for some other people) but for v3 solution does make sense.

Comment: Wow. Ok, when maybe the reason is due to some composer caching… I know it does it, but it never struck me with problems. Instead of using `*` you can try `dev-master` on each dependency in the composer.json, like [this](https://gist.github.com/ianbytchek/0219bb0070dce80f907c) (added the autoload option as well). Again, leave only `composer.json` and `behat.yml` in the folder, and run `composer install`.

Comment: Can you run `composer install -vvv --profile` and send a output? Make sure the vendor dir is deleted before you do that.

Comment: One more interesting detail: You proposed to set all `dev-master` and it didn't work for me in Ubuntu VM (created by Puphpet in Vagrant) bot it does work on my local Windows. And that `composer.json` PhpStorm created for me with v3 - i can reload from it on windows but it does not work in VM with error http://pastebin.com/WXZAUKam I am new to Composer, what could be different in settings? (i didn't setup anything though)

Comment: All composer is just a PHP script packed in a phar. If it works differently this might be due to different versions in 99.9% cases. Try updating both to the latest, see if that helps.

Comment: Man, looks like i have found the problem. My PHP in VM didn't have curl extension. This is really strange behavior but instead of reporting about missing extension it installed me old version. Now when i did `apt-get install php5-curl` - composer installs me `v3` when I request `*`. Thank you for spending so much time on me :)

Comment: Please, update your answer and mention that php module `curl` must be present for right behaviour. :)